# Does the standard mandate that std::unordered_map place key value pairs together in memory?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, unordered-map

Does the C++ standard in effect mandate that a conforming implementation of `std::unordered_map` place each key and value together in memory?

I think the answer is yes since much of `std::unordered_map` is specified in terms of `std::pair` and I don't think the maneuvers necessary to hide the details of key value pairs that are disjoint in memory could be completely hidden but I'm not sure.

Comment: What do you really want to know? You can iterate on the pairs, so yes, they do exist.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Well it's a language lawyer question so I what I really want to know is... what does the standard mandate? ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard requires that the `value_type` for `std::map::iterator` be `std::pair<const key, T>`, so (for example) as you walk through the map with an iterator, each time you dereference the iterator, you get a `pair<const key, T>`.

The standard also mandates that (for example) that `emplace` returns an iterator "to the newly inserted element". At least by my reading, that means you can't have it store the key and value separately from each other, and just (for example) copy a key/value into a temporary location, so it can return a pointer/reference to that location on demand.

The latter would (for example) violate exception safety requirements. It would have to do copying just to make elements in the collection visible, in cases where that's not allowed because such copying could throw an exception, but the function in question isn't allowed to do so (in fact, it's possible to emplace types that can't be copied at all).

Answer (score 2):

Requirement for map iterator to point to `std::pair<const Key, T>` and reqirement that object to which iterator refers does not change its address over time, makes it impossible to implement in other way. Said pair should exist and be persistent.

Potentially map can hold both key-value pairs for exposition and maintain internal copies of keys to search by them, but it is unefficient both for space and perfomance.